# Включение/выключение пошагового режима отладки программы

Tags: c++builder

Работаю в билдере 2010. Так получилось, что то ли компонент Indy заглючил, то ли что, в общем пришлось переустанавливать билдер, после чего прога заработала в конфигурации Release (я переключал). Если создаю новый проект, и пишу те же строчки кода, то Инди брыкается и к серверу не соединяется.

Но вопрос у меня маленько по другой части - после всей этой проделки с компонентами и конфигурациями опций проекта я не могу дебажить пошагово программу, ставлю точку красную эту слева в редакторе - что на цикле, что на объявлении переменных, или в любой другой части кода, при запуске у меня эта точка становится с крестиком, и ничего пошагово не делается, и в добавленные переменные в Watch List'е не показываются (собственно, как и сам Watch List). На конфигурацию Debug я боюсь переключаться по причине того, что весь проект рухнет (проделано работы по нему не мало). Вопрос в следующем - где в опциях что включить/выключить, что бы врубить пошаговый режим отладки программы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы активировать встроенный отладчик:

1. Выбрать раздел Tools > Options > Debugger Options
2. Отметить опцию Integrated Debugging
3. Кликнуть OK
4. Выборочно выставить другие настройки

Подробнее о настройках IDE:

- [Preparing a Project for Debugging](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preparing_a_Project_for_Debugging)
- [Using CodeGuard to Debug C++ Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_CodeGuard_to_Debug_C%2B%2B_Applications_Index)

Comment: Самое смешное, что и этот метод не работает =/ Причем только в одном проекте. При создании нового, и создания простейшего цикла - всё норм останавливает там, где требуется. Может это просто не предусмотренно конфигурацией Release?
Сейчас поизучаю ссылки, спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрел - много интересного, но включить Breakpoints так и не смог.

Answer (score 0):

[Включение и выключение режима "Изменить и продолжить"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7yty6a48.aspx)

Не это?

Comment: Нет.